# The Spectrum of the derivative operator in a specific Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, semigroup-of-operators, unbounded-operators

Consider the Banach space $X=\left\{u\in C^1([0,1]):\, u(0)=0\right\}$ and the subspace $D=\{u\in C^2([0,1]):\, u(0)=u(1)=u'(0)=0\}$, and the operator $A:D\longrightarrow X$ defined by $Au=u'$. I have made attempts to compute the spectrum and the resolvent operator (if it exists) for $A$ by solving the equation
$$\lambda u-u'=f,$$
for some $f\in X$, but I have not succeeded. I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide assistance.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this operator even well defined? Why must the derivative of an element in $D$ be in $X$?

Comment: thank you very much for your remark.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the issue of surjectivity. If you have $\lambda u - u' = f$ for $u \in D$ and $f \in X$ then you have $(e^{-\lambda t} u)' = -e^{-\lambda t} f$. Since $u(0) = 0$ this gives you the *unique* solution in $C^1([0, 1])$ of:
$$u(t) = -e^{\lambda t} \int_0^t e^{-\lambda x} f(x) d x$$
Then note that say $f(x) = x$ is $C^1([0, 1])$, has $f(0) = 0$, and $u(0) = u'(0) = 0$. But $u(1) < 0$ for any $\lambda$.

To have a non-empty resolvent you could have:

- $D = \{u \in C^2([0, 1]) : u(0) = u'(0) = 0\}$
- $X = \{u \in C^1([0, 1]) : u(0) = 0\}$

which sidesteps this issue with $u(1)$, which will necessitate a "zero-average condition" of sorts.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, @GeorgeCoote. In the last notification, I don't believe that $D$ is a subspace of $X$. The operator $A$ is supposed to map from a subset $D\subset X$ to $X$.

Comment: sorry yeah, I'll revise my answer